# How to map user data from Firestore

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to get the user's age and username, via `.map`, but it displays the last user signed in info, instead of the current one.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in `snapshot.data().map`, but I have no idea on how to change it to current user.

```
func getData() {

        let db = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
        
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid
        else {
            self.errorMessage = "Could not find firebase uid"
            return
        }
        
        db.collection("user").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            
            if error == nil {
                //No errors
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { 

                        self.userInfo = snapshot.data().map { d in
                            
                            return UserInfo(age: d["age"] as? Int ?? 18, username: d["username"] as? String ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                self.errorMessage = "Uh Oh... Error"
            }
        }
    }
```

And on the view, I have it displayed as:

`Text("\(userMng.userInfo?.username ?? "NoUsername"), \(userMng.userInfo?.age ?? 18)")`

Answer (score 0):

For getting current signed in users data you will need a Model.

example of the Model:

```
struct User{
    var uid: String 
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var username: String
    var email: String
    var gender: String
    var age: Int

}
```

Then you will need a viewModel to connect your model and view together, here is where you will do the firebase call.

example of viewModel:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class SignedInUser: ObservableObject{
    
    private var auth = Auth.auth()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    @Published var user: User?
    
    
    init(){
        fetchCurrentUser()
    }
    
    private func fetchCurrentUser(){
      
        guard let uid = auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }

        db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("Failed to fetch current user", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = snapshot?.data() else{ return }
            
            let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let surname = data["surname"] as? String ?? ""
            let username = data["username"] as? String ?? ""
            let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
            let gender = data["gender"] as? String ?? ""
            let age = data["age"] as? Int ?? 0
            
            self.user = User(uid: uid, name: name, surname: surname, username: username, email: email, gender: gender, age: age)

            
            
        })
    }
```

There you will get the current user by getting the signed in user uid and searching for it in firebase then you will check for errors and if successful you will call snapshotquery for the data, when you have the data you will map out all the data and set it as User.

You can then use that user in your view.

Example of view:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth

struct HomeScreenView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var vm = SignedInUser()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color("BG")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                Text("Current user: \(vm.user?.name ?? "")")
                Text("Home View")
                Text("\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")")
                Button(action: {
                    try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Logout")
                })
            }//VStack
        }//ZStack

        
    }
}

struct HomeScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeScreenView()
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you.